# Android - button height does not change

Tags: android, button, height

I am unable to make the height of my button smaller. Here's what I have in my xml:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/button_small_left"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_height="10px"
        android:height="10px"
        android:minHeight="10px"
        android:maxHeight="10px"
        android:padding="0px"
        android:textSize="6dip"
        android:text="asd"
/>
```

The button still shows up with a big top and bottom padding after this. The text appears in the middle. The button is used inside a relative layout.

Comment: Adding `android:layout_height="10px"` should be doing the job. It's working fine on my side. What OS are u working on...?

Comment: from your xml code its work fine also for me. have you forgot about layout_width:"" or its not necessary for you?

Comment: Have you tried to color your elements with different background colors in order to make sure it is the button element which causing the trouble and not the layout put on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strange - this does work fine when I created a new project to try again. The problem should have been somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead px (pixel) use dp(density pixel) for buttons height and width.

Ex:

```
android:layout_height="10dp"
```

and for text size use only sp(scale index pixel)

```
android:textSize="6sp"
```

In your above xml you forget to give width attribute.

```
android:layout_width="40dp"
```